# How to reuse algorithms from previous paper

Tags: citations, writing

In the past, I wrote a paper which included 2 algorithms A and B. Both of them were presented and fully explained. Moreover, B was built based on A, in other words, reader must know about A in order to understand B.

At the moment, I'm writing another paper which further expands B. However, it requires A to be presented (and explained) so that reader can understand. So, I wonder how to present an algorithm A in my new paper. So far, I have 3 solution:

- Present and fully explain A in a new paper
- Present A and say that its explanation is included in an old paper
- State that an algorithm in a new paper in based on algorithm A in an old one, without presenting or explaining it.

Comment: I would certainly not recommend option 3. A paper that is not self-contained (i.e., you need to dig out another paper to be reasonably able to make sense of the current paper) is typically rejected.

Answer (score 7):

You can create a Preliminaries section, and include Algorithm A and its explanation there clearly citing it. That way, it is clear to the reader that the second contains necessary background information, and not new contributions.

As far as how much to include, that really depends on how crucial it is for understanding of expansion of B, how much space you have available, whether the algorithm is published. Any other approaches you suggest are viable.

Comment: I like the idea of having a preliminaries section (in my field usually called "Background").

Comment: @xLeitix Well, in CS (we speak about algorithms, right?), it's Preliminaries :)

Comment: But, does that mean I have to cite the whole section about algorithm A from the old paper?

Comment: @user12635 You should explain Algorithm A as much as it is needed for understanding of your paper. The goal is to make the paper self-sufficient and not to require the readers to go and look up your other publication. How much you need to include, that depends on the particular Algorithm.

Comment: @tohecz No, there is no such standard in (theoretical) computer science. I have used "Preliminaries", "Background", "Prior Results", and even "Dramatis Personae".

Comment: @JeffE Ok, that's possible. I've only seen some hundreds of papers, but most of them from quite a narrow CS sub-community :)